# What "Tab" of "Tab.Columns" means on this code

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm trying to translate to VB the C# code I found in [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/288850/Using-SCOPE-IDENTITY-with-CommandBuilder-and-DataA). I was pretty successful but having troubles with `Tab` in  `foreach(DataColumn C in Tab.Columns)`.

Apparently its not a global variable... but he didn't define it anywhere.

The method is this one:

```
private void My_OnRowUpdate(object sender, OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{             
   if(e.StatementType==StatementType.Insert) 
   {                
      // reads the identity value from the output parameter @ID
      object ai = e.Command.Parameters["@ID"].Value;

      // updates the identity column (autoincrement)                   
      foreach(DataColumn C in Tab.Columns)
      {
         if(C.AutoIncrement)
         {
            C.ReadOnly = false;                      
            e.Row[C] = ai;  
            C.ReadOnly = true;
            break; // there can be only one identity column
         }      
      }                        

      e.Row.AcceptChanges();             
   }
}
```

Maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: We can't be sure because you haven't posted all the relevant code, but it seems to be the name of an instance of `DataTable`. If you're using Visual Studio, you can right click on on the word click 'Go to Definition' to get a hint.

Comment: I posted the Source http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/288850/Using-SCOPE-IDENTITY-with-CommandBuilder-and-DataA

 im translating another´s one code so i cant go to the source :(

Thanks for the answer anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `RowUpdated` event passes the [`OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbrowupdatedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) as argument you can simply use it's [`Row`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.rowupdatedeventargs.row(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get a reference to the table. That's better than in the article:

```
private void My_OnRowUpdate(object sender, OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{             
   if(e.StatementType==StatementType.Insert) 
   {                
      // reads the identity value from the output parameter @ID
      object ai = e.Command.Parameters["@ID"].Value;

      // updates the identity column (autoincrement)                   
      foreach(DataColumn C in e.Row.Table.Columns)
      {
         if(C.AutoIncrement)
         {
            C.ReadOnly = false;                      
            e.Row[C] = ai;  
            C.ReadOnly = true;
            break; // there can be only one identity column
         }      
      }                        

      e.Row.AcceptChanges();             
   }
}
```

Comment: Well tons of thanks ill try your way, but you forget im translating to vb! :P

Fortunately for me i found the answer in the mid time Tab means TBL in vb .net.

Anyway ill use your code because its simplier to translate.

Thanks a lot!